# Jmeter Response Times vs Threads

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, stress-testing

I am doing API load testing by sending 250 requests at once.

**1. Configuration**

[image]

Naturally, server takes longer to respond when a lot of users requests it simultaneously, this is what it says here.. As per http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads/.  However when testing this is what I found..

**2. Test**

[image]

The plot above starts from right to left and as the number of active threads decrease, the response time increases.

Is **active threads** same as **number of user requests**, if so why this is happening on a consistent basis?

**Update-1**
Ran another test and increased the ramp-up period this time

1. No of threads: 200
2. Ramp-Up Period: 200 secs
3. Loop Count: 200

[image]

Comment: hi, any feedback on answer ? thx

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 possible explanations:

- you don't have a problem, and your improvement in response times comes from caching effect related to your data being in cache after some time. Only you can validate as we don't know if you are using a large enough dataset and how long is your test lasting
- you have a problem, your server is rejecting connections under load, so you have very rapid failed responses that have a very good response time. To know if it's your problem, check the response code over time or transactions over time as long as error percentage

Comment: I don't believe its a problem either, but there is no caching going on. All the responses are success. I have updated the question with another plot which is what I was looking earlier. Keeping ramp-up time to 0 earlier was for stress testing, so that behavior is still a question to me.